# Apple Push Notification -- is it possible to make a batch request for a large number of notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I need to push notification to 10,000 users. Do I need to make 10,000 requests to the Apple APNS server ? Could I do it in a batch way ?

If I need to send the push requests one by one, is there any significant time difference between the first user and the last user when they receive the notification ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to clarify, you cannot send 1 identical message to more than one recipient in a broadcast like manner. However you *can* make one connection to the APNS server and send 10,000 messages in one session.  Since each message is quite small, 10,000 messages will not take that long to send on any decent connection to the internet.  I can't give you a specific time duration, as it will depend on what is between you and the APNS server.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there is no way to tell APNS to push a message to all devices that are registered to receive notifications from your app so yeah, you have to do it one by one.

With 10000 users there shouldn't a noticeable delay between first and last user. Since every device has a different network connection, notifications are usually at least a few hundreds of milliseconds late anyway.